# Image on image in bulk help please

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I hope that some kind soul could take time out to write me a very clear explanation of how to perform the following task, I am told that this can be done in photoshop through actions and or batch processing but for a guy in his mid fifties I am struggling to grasp the exact steps required.

Here is what I need to do & how I currently do it. I sell on ebay & Amazon personalized gifts such as coffee mugs, mouse pads etc. I have close on two million images in my library & I need to create mock ups for my entire library across all my blank products which stands at about fifty products just now.

I use CS3 & this is how I currently perform the task.

1) Open blank image (let's say a coffee mug)
2) Open an image folder & open the first image in that folder.
3) Magic wand
4) Inverse
5) Move tool to drag image onto coffee mug
6) Free transform to make the image fit the coffee mug.
7) Save
8) Delete top image & leave the blank coffee mug visible & start all over again.

As you can imagine this is taking forever. There are plenty of free mock up generators online but they only let you work on one at a time.

The majority of the images are jpgs on white backgrounds & they differ in size from say 300kb to 1.5mb

I have a very limited understanding. I have been able to apply a smart object / layer mask but it brings in a white area which I think is due to the fact that there is colour behind the image that I drag over, so I have just about figured how to make it transparent / remove colour behind the images. But when I try to batch process or load in stack it just says that smart objects can not be loaded.

I am a my wits end with this, so frustrating I think I nearly have it but I cannot crack it.

If anyone out there knows how to do this please could you write me some clear idiot proof step by step instructions.

Thank you in advance.

Eddie

Comment: Could you upload say 5 or so images and the coffee mug template? I could give you a general break-down but I would be missing a lot of details. This kind of automation is usually pretty specific to the template.